# SolveAlways keeps on loading

Tags: equation-solving

We have the function $f(x)=e^x((Ax+B)\cos(3x)+(Cx+D)\sin(3x))$. I need to find A,B,C,D in the following equation $f'''(x)+2f''(x)+10f'(x)=4x*e^x*cos(3x)$. When I use SolveAlways, it just says "Running" and nothing happens. I have solved it on paper and the final system of equations is pretty simple. The difficult part was to get the third derivative but mathematica doesn't have a problem with that. I can't understand why it can't solve it.

EDIT:
I have tried using:

```
f[x_]:=Exp[x]*((a*x+b)*Cos[3*x]+(c*x+d)*Sin[3*x])
SolveAlways[f'''[x]+2*f''[x]+10*f'[x] == 4*x*Exp[x]*Cos[3*x], x]
```

The above code just keeps on running and nothing happens. Also, I tried using `Simplify` but that didn't help at all. Note that running `Simplify` on the equation itself works fine but for some reason it can't solve it.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far (i.e., MMA codes).

Comment: Solve works fine for me.`Solve[D[f, {x, 3}] + D[f, {x, 2}] + D[f, x] == 4 x E^x + Cos[3 x], {a,
   b, c, d}]`